# Backup of Dashdb on Bluemix - what options available

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb, ibm-cloud-tools

I tried taking backup of dashdb from bluemix cloud using Data Studio. I am getting this error *'Remote target is unreachable.'*.

Since this is an admin activity, I assume it should be done on the server. As this is cloud server, I am trying to understand how this can be done!

Are there any tools which support ssh to the server and how to take backup of the db? Any documentation in this regard?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which plan are you using ?

Have you read the details of backup on the [FAQ](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/managed_service.html) ?

This section might help:

> Is my data backed up?    Encrypted backups on the full Db2 managed service database are done daily. For the Db2 Warehouse on Cloud Flex Performance plan, the
>   last 7 daily backups are retained. For all other Db2 Warehouse on
>   Cloud plans, the last 2 daily backups are retained. For Db2 on Cloud,
>   the last 14 daily backups are retained. In the Db2 Warehouse on Cloud Flex Performance plan, you can restore your database from any of your retained backups at any time
>   that you choose. In the case of all of the other Db2 Warehouse on
>   Cloud plans, the retained backups are used exclusively by IBM for only
>   system recovery purposes in the event of a disaster or system loss. A
>   request to restore your database from a backup is not supported. You
>   can export your data using Db2 tools such as IBM Data Studio or by
>   using the db2 export command.> 
>       For Db2 on Cloud, backups can be stored off site in a different data center or region upon request to IBM Support. These backups are
>   also used exclusively by IBM to recover from only disaster or system
>   loss events. A request to restore your database from a backup is not
>   supported.

Comment: Yes, I have read this. We are exploring to take backup at lesser intervals, say once in 4 hours. That is why i am looking for ways of manual backup

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any tools which support ssh to the server and how to take backup of the db? Any documentation in this regard?

SSH is not supported as this is a managed service. This is documented in [the FAQ](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/managed_service.html):

> How do I access the Db2 managed service database?
>   You can access your Db2 managed service database through the web console from a browser, or you can connect to the database with a client connection such as JDBC, ODBC, CLI, CLP, or CLPPlus. A direct login to the server with Telnet or a Secure Shell (ssh) is not supported.

If you want to take your own backups at the interval of your choice, exporting your data is your best option. That can be done from the web console or from a database client.

Alternatively, if what you're after is access to historical data, you can use [time travel query](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/426878/how-do-i-use-time-travel-query-in-db2-or-db2-on-cl.html).